# Do I need more VRAM?

Tags: rendering

I was doing some work that ended up having lots of linked models, there were different types of textures for the same box. When I see my pre render VRAM its 1/12 Gb. But when I start rendering it just freezes as a message in the top left of the render window appears as out of memory. Or it just shuts down. What could it be?[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280520/110840 - you don't list your gpu, but this may help if you have an rtx card

Comment: Now I'm using a rtx 3060, I tried the CUDA to render and had the same message, not enough memory, the real problem is that I dont know which is lacking I thought it was VRAM but it doesn't look like it is

Answer (score 0):

You could use the duplicate technic may to save vram. [Blender-Manual-Duplication](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/duplication.html)

It´s in the Graphic-Industry always good to have a lot of VRam. But 3D-Programs like Blender have a lot of tricks inside to reduce the amount of necessary Ram.You could also switch to CPU Rendering or Cloud-Rendering.

Comment: Yeah so I tried the CPU mode but had the same problem. The duplication between the displays I made with the duplication shift+D so I don't know if the alt+D alternative is going to make any difference. I'm going to try the cloud rendering. Thanks fo the attettion